# How to display firebase data to a chart in MVC web application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, firebase-realtime-database, highcharts

[Firebase structure] [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rnda.png)How to display firebase data to a chart in MVC web application?
I have a static spline with symbols from highcharts.com as my template, I have a realtime firebase database with Y and X axes. I just need a way to link the two to display a meaningful chart in an MVC web application using VS Studio 2019. Thank you!

Comment: Hi, How look your data? Highcharts expects data usually as an array. `https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series`

Comment: Hi Sebastian, Thank you for the link. I have added a snip of my database on the description. "Firebase structure"

Comment: Here you will find examples whereby to connect your data to MVC https://dotnet.highcharts.com/